# playing audio in event listener still gives error

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, audio

I have this in the window `load` listener function.

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = "assets/silence.mp3";
audio.load();
document.getElementById("body").addEventListener(
  'touchstart',
  function(evt){ audio.play(); audio = 0; },
  {capture:false,once:true,passive:true}
);
```

In chrome on android (with remote debugging open), I touch the screen and it (correctly) triggers trying to play the audio. However, it fails and logs this to the console:

`(index):65 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.`

How else am I supposed to trigger audio in a way that ensures the user initiates it, if not through a user interaction event listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aha. turns out, `touchstart` doesn't count as a "user interaction" from the perspective of the mechanisms preventing auto-play.

solution: swap it with `click`.

one thing I'm still frustrated with:

I'm using this specific snippet as a means of very quickly allowing audio to be played on the page so that the underlying html5 game can play audio without worrying about it being blocked by the browser.

however- because it needs to wait for a full "click" event (as opposed to a "touchstart" event), any audio that *should* be triggered on "touchstart" is going to be passed over (for the first time it would otherwise be triggered).
it seems like 1. there's no way to get around this to use it how I'd like, and 2. if you're able to just listen to the whole document for a "click" anyways, it's not actually doing anything from stopping unwanted audio.

If anyone can come up with a better solution, I'll swap the "correct answer" to that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was making a web piano. The browser charged the piano on load, so you could press(actually touch the screen) the piano keys before you click something. What I did was to add a starting screen with a button to start the game and this solved it because you had to click something before you touch the piano keys.